# RODBC: execute a query containing multiple statements

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have a stored procedure that returns a varbinary output parameter. I want to call it from R and capture the return variable. I tried:

```
qq <- "declare @mm varbinary(max); exec spTrain_df_to_op @mm_outer = @mm output; select @mm as model;"
conStr <- "Driver={SQL Server};Server=.;Database=airline_new;Trusted_Connection=TRUE;"
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(conStr, rows_at_time = 1)
result <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, qq)
```

This fails and result comes out as character(0). It may be that RODBC does not want to execute what is essentially a sequence of queries. How would I go around that?

Thank you!

Here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTrain_df_to_op]
  @mm_outer varbinary(max) output
AS
  BEGIN TRY
    exec sp_execute_external_script
      @language = N'R',
      @script = N'
        func <- function() {
          in_df[,"DayOfWeek"] <- factor(in_df[,"DayOfWeek"], levels=as.character(1:7))
          # The model formula
          formula <- ArrDelay ~ CRSDepTime + DayOfWeek + CRSDepHour:DayOfWeek
          # Train the model
          rxSetComputeContext("local")
          mm <- rxLinMod(formula, data=in_df, transformFunc=NULL, transformVars=NULL)
          mm <<- serialize(mm, connection=NULL)
        }
        result = func()
      ',
      @input_data_1 = N'select top 10000 ArrDelay,CRSDepTime,DayOfWeek,CRSDepHour from cleanData',
      @input_data_1_name = N'in_df',
      @params = N'@mm varbinary(max) output',
      @mm = @mm_outer output
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
  END CATCH;
```

For kicks I tried the following:

```
qq = "declare @mm varbinary(max); select 2 as hello; select 1 as model"
conStr <- "Driver={SQL Server};Server=.;Database=airline_new;Trusted_Connection=TRUE;"
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(conStr, rows_at_time = 1)
result <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, qq)
```

This returns only the result of the 1st query:

```
  hello
1     2
```

I also tried setting the query to

```
qq = paste0("SET NOCOUNT ON; declare @mm varbinary(max); ",
           "exec spTrain_df_to_op @mm_outer = @mm output; ",
           "SET NOCOUNT OFF; select @mm as model;")
```

That still produced character(0).

Creating a stored procedure out of the queries is not an option.

Comment: The qq thing is a typo sorry. Are you suggesting adding a select statement to the end of the stored procedure, that selects all of the output parameters?

Comment: The issue is that the stored procedure also returns a result set that is not an output parameter. Sometimes I need the result set, other times output parameters. .

Comment: It just returns character(0) as a result

Comment: What does the corresponding lines output in SQL Server?

Comment: The same query works properly through SSMS and returns a varbinary as a single entry in the table under the column model.

Comment: also it is important for me not to change the output parameters of the stored procedure since it may be called from SSMS or C# as well... So unfortunately I cannot get rid of the output parameters and just declare variables inside the SP and then select them... I also cannot lump all the statements into another SP since I may not have permissions to register it with a db

Comment: Can you provide code of *spTrain_df_to_op* for reproducibility? I just ran similar lines on a test stored procedure and data did return in R.

Comment: Just added it to the main post

Comment: I am curios to see what you tried and if my issue is due to something with sp_execute_external_script or some weird package configuration. However, it seems to execute fine from SSMS

Comment: You are calling an R function in SQL Server and then want output back in R? Why not import the `cleanData` query and run `func` function in R?

Comment: Unfortunately that would not work for me... it has to be executed in db.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RODBC command 'sqlQuery' has problems with table variables in t-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396013/rodbc-command-sqlquery-has-problems-with-table-variables-in-t-sql)

Comment: Unfortunately their solution did not work for me

Answer (score 4):

**Admittedly I haven't tried this for PL/SQL as in your use case, but think it should work, if not hopefully it us useful for someone else for running multiple queries stored in a single script.**

You should be able to accomplish this by first splitting the script into the individual queries. If you use semi colon as a delimiter (which is how many queries are set up anyway, and how your second attempt was constructed) you can split the query into a vector of queries and run each individually via a loop. If certain queries have results that you would like to access afterwards you can return them and store them in a list as you go.

```
library(RODBC)

# an example SQL Script containing multiple queries, seperated by semi-colon
example_script <- 
"select sysdate from dual;
commit;
select sysdate from dual;"

# split the string into a character vector of queries to run
split_queries <- strsplit(example_script, ";",)[[1]]

#prepeare a list to store results
list_of_results <- list() 


ch <- odbcConnect("XX",uid="XX", pwd="XX")

# loop through and run the queries, storing results (if any) in the list
for (i in 1:length(split_queries)) {

  list_of_results[[i]] <- sqlQuery(ch,
                                   split_queries[i],
                                   errors = FALSE)

  Sys.sleep(2)

}

odbcClose(ch)

# show list of results, of course these elements could be anything from strings to data.frames
list_of_results

[[1]]
              SYSDATE
1 2018-03-28 17:15:26

[[2]]
[1] -2

[[3]]
              SYSDATE
1 2018-03-28 17:15:30
```

- I have put a "commit;" in to illustrate that a command that doesn't
  have results will just return a negative integer in the list of results for that
  position.
- I include errors = FALSE in sqlQuery as this will allow for commands like
  "drop table" when the table doesn't exist in the first place to work
  without stopping the loop.

I have large scripts that have multiple **drop table** **create table** pairs of queries. This method allows me to bring the entire script into R in one piece and run in one go. Typically I am only after the results from the final query so I won't store things in a list as I go, rather just have a single output variable which get's overwritten as the loop runs until the final select statement dumps the results out into the variable.