# My R code is not fetching data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r

While the normal Select statements used on R are fetching the data, I am not able to fetch the data using SQL on the following query:
The SQL part is working on SQL Server 2008. Also, I am using RStudio
Any suggestions what is wrong here?

```
qf<-sqlQuery(mycon,"USE MDM_STAT
+ DECLARE @RUNMONTH INT;
+              DECLARE @RUNYEAR INT;
+              DECLARE @PERIOD INT;
+              DECLARE @FISCALRUNYEAR INT;
+              DECLARE @FISCALRUNYEAR_BEGIN INT;
+              SET @RUNMONTH=MONTH(GETDATE());
+              SET @RUNYEAR=YEAR(GETDATE());
+              SET @PERIOD=
+              CASE 
+              WHEN @RUNMONTH>3 THEN (@RUNMONTH-3)
+              ELSE 9+@RUNMONTH
+              END
+              ;
+              SET @FISCALRUNYEAR=
+              CASE
+              WHEN @RUNMONTH>3 THEN @RUNYEAR
+              ELSE @RUNYEAR-1
+              END
+              ;
+              SET @FISCALRUNYEAR_BEGIN=
+              CASE
+              WHEN @PERIOD=12 THEN @FISCALRUNYEAR
+              ELSE @FISCALRUNYEAR-1
+              END
+              ;
+              
+              select * from dbo.TEMP_CUST_OPERATING_PROFIT OP
+              where OP.Sales_Year=@FISCALRUNYEAR
+              AND OP.PERIOD<=@PERIOD
+              UNION
+              select * from dbo.TEMP_CUST_OPERATING_PROFIT OP
+              where OP.Sales_Year=@FISCALRUNYEAR_BEGIN
+              AND OP.PERIOD>@PERIOD")
```

Comment: You need `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first statement in your SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RODBC command 'sqlQuery' has problems with table variables in t-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396013/rodbc-command-sqlquery-has-problems-with-table-variables-in-t-sql)

Comment: @nrussell Using that command,
I am getting the following errors if I use SET NOCOUNT ON:
> qf
[1] "42000 195 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]'No' is not a recognized SET option."                                                                                                        [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect

Comment: @nrussell.. I am getting the following errors upon using SET NOCOUNT ON;
> qf
[1] "42000 195 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]'No' is not a recognized SET option."                                                                 
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect

Comment: It's late, but still, if I have a query like that, I'll definitely create a stored procedure instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow the following steps:

1) You should make sure the the connection string is set correctly for establishing the correct connection with the database. 
a quite good explanation appears here: [short youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5QEEQhpRbQ)

2) in R write:

```
library(RODBC)   
channel = odbcConnect("The_database_name_your_are_connecting_to")
...
sqlQuery(channel ,"your query here")
close(channel)
```

I suggest you to start with the simplest query and after you made sure it worked,
go with a more complex query

hope it would work for you, good luck!

Comment: I did start with a query as simple as that and it did work. It is only this type of query that is not working